# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException:

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Face: ");
    pickedf = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Value: ");
    pickedv = scan.nextInt();
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at FlipRace.main(FlipRace.java:24)
```

I know it has something to do with the scanner but I have no idea what.

Comment: Line 24 is the "pickedf = scan.nextLine();"

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm beginner in Java.. mind elaborating?

Comment: I have deleted the previous comment as it was unrelated. Are you inputting some alpha / non-numeric character(s) to an input to this line `pickedv = scan.nextInt();`? If so then, you need to use `scan.nextLine()` instead. `scan.nextInt()` doesn't handle it. Your program appears to attempt to read a value that cannot be represented to an `integer` type.

Comment: What part of [the documentation for nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) is confusing you? The input isn't an `int`

Answer (score 2):

If "Value" is supposed to be an integer like -1, 0, 5,  your code in fine. You're just typing in something else. If it's supposed to be anything else like 2.5 (float/double), or "Ugly Face" (string), then you need to change the last code you included to

```
pickedv = scan.nextLine();
```

instead.

Comment: But see the problem isnt with pickedv, it's with pickedf. Im putting in heads for the face and .25 for the value. And Im getting the error for the pickedf which is line 24

Comment: If you're typing in your values one at a time, you wouldn't be able to get to where you input values (pickedv part). If you got to the part of the code that prints out "Values" and you typed in .25, the pickedf part works. And .25 shouldn't be a valid value with the code above, where "heads" for face should be (I copied your code and it works on my machine). And if the "Value" can be a fraction like .25, you should probably change that last line to pickedv = scan.nextDouble(); or scan.nextFloat();